# Quadratic forms and orthogonal basis

Tags: quadratic-forms, orthogonal-matrices

I have the quadratic form $q(x,y,z) = x^2 - 2y^2 +xz +yz$

1. Give the polar form and the matrix of q in canonic basis.
   I think this question is ok :
   $$
    A = \begin{pmatrix}
     1 & 0 & 1/2 \\
     0 & -2 & 1/2 \\
     1/2 & 1/2 & 0 
    \end{pmatrix}
   $$

$$ f(u,u') = x x'-2 y y' + \frac{1}{2}(xz' + x'z) + \frac{1}{2}(yz' + y'z)$$

2. Find an orthogonal basis for q.
   I am not 100% sure of my answer :
   If first used Gauss algorithm and found
   $$ q(x,y,z) = \left(x+\frac{1}{2} z \right)^2 - 2\left(y-\frac{1}{4}z \right)^2 - \frac{1}{8}z^2 $$

Then I deduced the matrix
$$ B=
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  0\\
  0
 \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  1\\
  0
 \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -\frac{1}{2}\\
  \frac{1}{4}\\
  1
 \end{pmatrix}
\right) 
$$

3. Check if B is orthogonal finding the q matrix in the basis B from A: do I have to do a diagonalization?

Could q matrix in basis B be $\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & -2 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & -1/8
 \end{pmatrix}$ ?

4. Give a basis for q orthogonal in the plane generated by the two first vectors of canonic basis.
   I am still looking how to start this question.

Thanks for your help.